# bash echo to a file fails with "no such file"

Tags: bash

```
declare -r bdbLocation='/root/scripts/bashDB/'
BDBconnect () {
  set -u
  local file="$bdbLocation$1"
  [[ -f "$file" ]] && echo "$file" || BTKerror "DB File $file does not exist."
}
BDBinsert () {
  local file=$(BDBconnect "$1")
  grep "$2" -q "$file" && { BTKerror "The file ${file} already contains ${2}, use update rather than insert."; exit 1; }
  case $4 in
    r) local entry="declare -r ${2}=\"${3}\"" ;;
    A | a | i | rA | Ar | ra | ar | ir | ri) local entry="declare -${4} ${2}=${3} " ;;
    *) local entry="${2}=\"${3}\"" ;;
  esac
  echo "$entry" >> "$file"
  grep "$entry" -q "$file" && BTKsuccess "Entry $entry correctly inserted into ${file}." || BTKerror "Entry $entry FAILED to insert into ${file}."
}
```

The above is called to a script in the same directory via source command.
BDBconnect function works and serves up the correct file and path.
the problem is the line under

```
esac
echo "$entry" >> "$file"
```

it throws a `"no such file or dir"` error.
The error function message says the file name and path are correct.

I have been trying to find the error for hours :(

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: do you have permissions to access the directory?

Comment: I thought it was `grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]` ?

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I think exact message is *`No such file or directory`*!!  Try `mkdir -p /root/scripts/bashDB`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a strange invisible character before and after the >>
A linux editor revealed the character, changed and all works now.